# Is "a me mi" nowadays accepted as correct written language?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

I remember when I was young that using "`a me mi`" was considered wrong.

For example saying `a me mi piace giocare a calcio`.

But I also remember that it was so largely used that it was made "legal" in the spoken language. I remember hearing it in the news.

What is the situation at the moment? Is it allowed in written language as well as in spoken language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"A me mi" è un [raddoppiamento clitico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/), un tipo di [dislocazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dislocazioni_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/).

Secondo molti si tratterebbe di un [pleonasmo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pleonasmo/), ripetizione di «una o più parole grammaticalmente o concettualmente non necessarie», dovuta ad enfasi.

Secondo l'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/forma-corretta) e la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/a-me-mi-a-te-ti_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) ciò non sarebbe del tutto corretto in quanto "a me" (pronome personale in forma tonica) significherebbe "quanto a me", ed avrebbe quindi un valore diverso da "mi" (pronome personale in forma atona), complemento di termine.

[Nel parlato formale](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_225.html) va evitato così come nello scritto formale, è chiaro che lo puoi usare anche nello scritto se il [registro](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/registro_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) lo richiede.

**EDIT** --> Short summary in English as required by IL

Some suggest "a me mi" is a pleonasm, the unnecessary repetition of one or more words, just to add emphasis to a sentence.

L'Accademia della Crusca and Treccani suggest there might be more to it: "a me" and "mi" might have different functions within the sentence.

"A me mi" should be avoided in formal spoken and written Italian, unless - of course - it is required by the chosen register.

Comment: As we agreed on [meta](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian), one should bear in mind that the answers should be useful not only for native speakers, so it'd make sense to answer in English to a question posed in English and in Italian to a question posed in Italian. It's a good answer (+1) but please consider adding an English translation with respect to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* 
(Il Mulino, Bologna, 2015), Vittorio Coletti explains that this construction is an example of what is called "dislocazione a sinistra": it consists of a complement which is written at the beginning of a sentence and then repeated in the sentence in the form of a clitic pronoun, so as to give more emphasis to that complement. For instance,

> La mela, l'ha mangiata Mario.

Coletti explains that the construction "a me mi" has been used in Italian for centuries to emphasize the role of the speaker as the object of what is being said. Nevertheless, he advises to accurately avoid it in written Italian. In his words:

> Qualsiasi complemento può essere dislocato (il costrutto è detto dislocazione a sinistra) in questo modo e poi ripreso con un pronome: «a Venezia ci andrò la prossima settimana», «a Mario non glielo dico». Rientra in questa tipologia di costrutti anche il famigerato e fastidioso «a me mi» («a me mi sembra strano»), da evitare perché mal giudicato, in realtà espressione di un costrutto secolare dell'italiano, usato per dare evidenza al ruolo dell'io come destinatario; è come se si dicesse «quanto a me, mi...». Evitiamolo accuratamente nello scritto, per carità, ma se qualcuno ci fa notare che è, oltre che sbagliato, brutto, proponiamogli questa frase: «a me, il comportamento di Mario, con tutte le sue esitazioni e rinvii, ripensamenti e dubbi, non mi convince del tutto», e vedrà che il doppio pronome gli sembrerà molto meno brutto e anche meno sbagliato, in questa collocazione più distanziata, pur aggiungendosi qui al raddoppiamento del pronome («a me ... mi») la costruzione con preposizione («a me») di un complemento che, nell'italiano standard, il verbo (*convincere*) vuole invece diretto, senza preposizione (anche se l'accusativo preposizionale è frequente negli italiani regionali del meridione).

Answer (score -1):

```
mi piace giocare a calcio
```

e

```
a me piace giocare a calcio.
```

sono corrette, perchè indicano **una sola volta** il complemento di termine (a me / mi)

```
a me mi piace giocare a calcio.
```

è scorretta perchè ci sono **due complementi di termine** (a me / mi) **riferiti alla medesima persona** (me).

Si rafforza un concetto già espresso chiaramente.

Nel parlato questo costrutto è più diffuso e permesso nell'Italia Settentrionale, per la genesi dei dialetti della zona

Comment: “questo costrutto è più diffuso e permesso nell'Italia Settentrionale”: interessante. Fonte?

Comment: "a mi me piase la brios!" (una vecchia pubblicità). Scherzi a parte, "a me mi" mi è sempre suonato come un dialettismo, bisognerebbe vedere in quali dialetti è una forma usuale.

Comment: A onor del vero, ho appena scoperto che l'Accademia della Crusca non lo considera un errore nell'italiano parlato (http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/forma-corretta). Alla fine, afferma che nella struttura logica della frase è errata, ma nella comunicazione va bene perchè permette alcune sfumature