# Uso di "a me mi piace"

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Girando su Internet ho incontrato varie discussioni riguardo alla correttezza grammaticale dell'espressione "a me mi piace".

A scuola e in famiglia ogni volta che un bambino utilizza tale forma per esprimersi gli adulti di solito tendono a sottolineare che è scorretta.

Tuttavia, sul sito dell'Accademia della Crusa riporta che in realtà dal punto di vista grammaticale non è sbagliato, in quanto non si tratta di una ripetizione inutile di due termini equivalenti, ma che ciascuno dei due abbia un suo significato indipendente e diverso dall'altro, ed è quindi possibile utilizzarla nel giusto contesto, che suppongo sia il parlato quotidiano piuttosto che lo scritto.

Fonte: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/forma-corretta

E quindi, dopo aver letto ciò mi sorge il dubbio fino a che punto sia corretto utilizzarla e in che contesto, poiché nella loro risposta citano diverse opere letterarie, tra l'altro anche abbastanza vecchie, senza dare una spiegazione diretta.

Devo considerare che è possibile usarla solo quando si parla in circostanze informali come in famiglia o potrebbe essere inserita anche in lettere/testi informali?

Comment: Io la utilizzerei solo in contesti (molto) informali, se non sei Manzoni mi sembra molto difficile azzeccare la sfumatura corretta per un suo uso scritto.

Comment: Io non lo userei mai in italiano, anche se lo tollero in contesti informali. Lo percepisco come un uso dialettale (in veneto, o almeno nella versione della mia zona, i raddoppiamenti di pronomi sono molto comuni)

Comment: Prendila come una battuta, ma... che cosa ti fa pensare che alcuni sconosciuti a caso in rete ne sappiano più della Crusca? :-)

Comment: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/is-a-me-mi-nowadays-accepted-a-correct-written-language

Comment: @DenisNardin: Curiosità: in veneto è comune o obbligatorio? Lo chiedo perché in catalano e in castigliano questo radoppiamento è infatti obbligatorio (l'ho pensato adesso che ho scritto una risposta su Spanish.SE su questo argomento). Cioè, per esempio, si deve dire "A mi m'agrada Italian.SE" invece di "*A mi agrada Italian.SE".

Comment: @Charo Poiché non è mai stato codificato, è difficile dire se sia davvero obbligatorio ma io certo lo percepisco come la forma "standard" ("A mi me piase Italian.SE"). Ferguson nel suo libro dice "As in French and Spanish, clitic doubling is normal in Venetian [...] in contrast to (standard) Italian where the original pronoun disappears after such a dislocation" (Ferguson, *A linguistic history of Venice*, 9.2.3).

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Interessante. La cosa curiosa è che, perlomeno [secondo Vittorio Coletti](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10876), in italiano questo è da ritenersi una dislocazione a sinistra, mentre invece in spagnolo e in catalano è considerato tutt'altro fenomeno (non so in veneto) poiché si deve anche dire  "El cine le gusta a María" (non si dice "El cine gusta a María").

Comment: Forse questo è un argomento interessante per chiedere qualcosa su linguistics.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20me%20mi%20piace%2Ca%20te%20ti%20piace&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20me%20mi%20piace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20te%20ti%20piace%3B%2Cc0)*** mostra un uso crescente delle espressioni  "*a me mi piace, a te ti piace*" negli ultimi decenni.

Anche ***[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/a-me-mi-a-te-ti_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)***, come l'Accademia della Crusca, sostiene che l'uso non è scorretto ma ne raccomanda un utilizzo informale e sconsiglia di usarle in contesti formali come colloqui di lavoro o esami scolastici.

***A ME MI, A TE TI***:

> - ***A me mi e a te ti sono casi particolari di quel fenomeno sintattico (detto dislocazione) che consiste nell’anticipare o posticipare un elemento della frase riprendendolo tramite un pronome.*** Un fenomeno attestato nell’uso dell’italiano fin dalle sue origini. Qui la ripresa riguarda il pronome personale, usato prima nella forma tonica (me), poi in quella atona (mi). ***Non si tratta propriamente di un pleonasmo (cioè di una ripetizione inutile), ma di una sottolineatura ottenuta mettendo in evidenza l’elemento che si ritiene più importante***.
>
>   - *A me mi sembra che le cose stiano molto diversamente.*

***USI***

> - ***Nel linguaggio parlato informale, un costrutto come a me mi è certamente consentito.***
> - ***Ma nel parlato formale*** (un colloquio di lavoro o una prova di esame orale, un dialogo con un superiore – docente, capoufficio ecc.) e ancor più nello scritto ***è decisamente da evitare, perché darebbe la sensazione che chi parla o scrive non sia capace di adeguare il proprio ➔registro linguistico alla situazione in cui si trova.***
> - ***Il costrutto è largamente attestato nell’uso letterario***
>
>   - *A me mi par di sì: potete domandare nel primo paese che troverete andando a diritta (A. Manzoni, I promessi sposi)*
> - ***e ritorna con una certa frequenza nelle canzoni degli ultimi trent’anni***:
>
>   - *coca cola sì coca cola / a me mi fa impazzire (V. Rossi, Bollicine)*
>   - *perché a me mi piace andare veloce (Jovanotti, La mia moto).*

Il dizionario ***[Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/a-me-mi-piace.shtml)*** sostiene che si tratta di una forzatura stilistica più che di una sgrammaticatura, di cui comunque, non è il caso di abusare:

> - Nella pubblicità televisiva di un caffè un famoso attore comico si è servito di questo “a me mi piace” pensando di fare una simpatica sgrammaticatura per attirare l’attenzione. ***L’attenzione c’è stata senz’altro; la sgrammaticatura no.***
> - ***Si tratta semplicemente dell’uso di un elemento sovrabbondante, inutile secondo la logica, ma utilissimo per dare alla frase un’efficacia particolare.*** È insomma la scelta dello stile che giustifica la lieve forzatura grammaticale dell’espressione: il valore rafforzativo di quel mi pleonastico è chiaro. Altri esempi: “a me non me la dai a intendere”; “lo so che a te non ti va questa faccenda”, “a voi non vi dirò più niente”.
> - ***Ma attenzione: non dimentichiamo che la frase non solo corretta, ma anche preferibile nel novanta per cento dei casi è “a me piace”, e così dicasi per gli altri esempi:*** “a me non la dai a intendere”, “lo so che a te non va questa faccenda”, “a voi non dirò più niente”.
> - ***A me mi, a te ti, a noi ci, a voi vi eccetera, seppure ammissibili, sono licenze stilistiche: sarà il caso di non abusarne.***

Comment: Però da Ngram si vede che negli ultimi anni l'uso di *a me mi* e *a te ti* sta drasticamente diminuendo, probabilmente perché se qualcuno lo scrive su FB tutti i suoi amici lo prendono in giro :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX - inserendo le espressioni generiche "a me mi, a te ti", l'uso appare crescente  anche negli ultimi anni. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+me+mi%2Ca+te+ti+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20me%20mi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20te%20ti%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Avevo guardato il link che hai messo nella risposta, poi non ho scritto il *piace* nel commento per abbreviare. Comunque un piccolo calo alla fine c'è anche per *a me mi, a te ti*, anche se può essere ciclico, vedremo cosa succederà nel futuro... :)

Comment: La usavamo continuamente per colpa di Vasco... moda che va e viene?