# Ci o vi secondo il contesto, ma in questo esempio quale sarebbe?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, pronouns, particles

Buonasera. Nel mio libro c'è un esercizio che dice: "Sei stato troppo duro con lui! Forse è meglio se ci parli da padre a figlio." Non dovrebbe essere "vi" invece? Perché è una terza persona parlando con il padre, probabilemente la mamma, ma l'esercizio dice "ci parli". Non dovrebbe essere "vi parli"? Perché sono soltanto il padre e il figlio.

Comment: Né *ci* né *vi*. Dovrebbe essere *gli*

Comment: Perché, @egreg? Che c'è che non va in “parlaci tu”? Come chiarisce la voce citata da Gio, non è lo stesso che sostituire “gli” con “ci” (come in “ce lo dico io”).

Comment: @DaG Pensi che “parlaci tu” sia proprio corretto?

Comment: @egreg. Sì, per questo ti chiedo che cosa c'è che non va.

Comment: @DaG Abbiamo idee diverse su questo, apparentemente: io considero “parlaci tu” scorretto, anche se purtroppo usato. Trovo assurdo che un libro di italiano per stranieri lo dia come corretto.

Comment: @egreg. Oltre alla voce citata da Gio, è pertinente questo estratto dalla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/):

Comment: «Riferito a persona, quando non mantiene in qualche modo il suo valore di avverbio locativo (come per es. nelle frasi: da loro io non ci vado volentieri; da quel ragazzo non ci si ricava nulla di buono), è corretto solo per significare «con lui, con lei, con loro», quando questi pronomi (o il nome della persona) sono già espressi o si possono facilmente sottintendere: con lui è tanto tempo che non ci vado più; ci discorreva già da un anno quando si sono fidanzati. È invece dialettale l’uso del ci nel senso di «a lui, a lei, a loro» (per es.: ci dissi, ci diedi, ci apro subito).»

Comment: Qui non sostituisce “gli”, ma è un lecito “con lui”.

Comment: Vedi anche http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2007/30novembre.shtml (cercando “parlaci”).

Comment: @egreg: «Trovo assurdo che un libro di italiano per stranieri lo dia come corretto», e il Sabatini-Colletti, e il Treccani, e lo Zingarelli («con lui, con lei, con loro: non ci vado d'accordo; non ci esco da un bel po'») e vari linguisti, e classici come il Petrocchi e il Fanfani...

Comment: @DaG Potrei anche, *obtorto collo*, accettare “parlaci tu”, ma qui non può essere “parla con lui da padre a figlio”, perché qui chi parla è il padre e il figlio ascolta. Quindi è “parla *a* lui da padre a figlio”.

Comment: @egreg: Che cos'ha che non va “parla con lui da padre a figlio”? “Ho parlato con mio figlio dei suoi problemi” non è più scorretto di “Ho parlato a mio figlio dei suoi problemi”; semmai ha una sfumatura diversa. No? EDIT: Forse ho capito: tu la vedi come una predica che fa il padre mentre il figlio ascolta zitto, mentre io immagino un dialogo fra i due. È così?

Comment: @DaG Esattamente. Non riesco proprio a convincermi che “ci” in questo caso sia un modo da insegnare ai principianti. Apre la strada a “ci ho detto che la smetta”.

Comment: @egreg - in realtà è molto diffuso e i vari dizionari ne confermano l'uso anche se in contesti informali. Probabilmente la grammatica su cui OP sta studiando dovrebbe precisare l'uso colloquiale e l'uso grammaticalmente più corretto.

Comment: Mi sembra che il “parlare da padre a figlio”, invece che in modo duro, sia un modo per dire che la persona deve parlare «con» e non «a», quindi il «ci» è il pronome giusto. Non vedo rischi verso usi “scorretti”…

Answer (score 2):

L'uso della particella pronominale "***ci***"  al posto del pronome personale "gli" viene considerato informale o regionale:

> - ***pron. dimostr.***  A ciò, di ciò ecc., con riferimento, anche generico, a cosa o a situazione: non ci pensare più; ci puoi giurare; ***con riferimento a pers. (a parte gli usi pop. e region. in cui sostituisce gli: ci dico), si adopera soltanto nel senso di “con lui”, “con lei”, “con loro” o sim., oppure in combinazione con un altro pron.: ci ho parlato; su di te non ci si può contare.***

Come pronome dimostrativo "***vi***" si usa in riferimento a luoghi o situazioni più che a persone:

> - con ciò, su ciò, con riferimento, anche generico, a cosa o situazione: non vi vedo niente di male; c'è una riunione importante, vi prenderà parte anche il presidente

(Sabatini Colletti)

Comment: Sono d'accordo sul fatto che questo uso di "ci" corrisponda al primo brano del Sabatini Colletti che hai citato, ma il dizionario non dice che si tratti di una sostituzione di "gli" con "ci" considerata colloquiale o regionale. Semplicemente si tratta di "è meglio se parli con lui" = "è meglio se ci parli".

Comment: È come l'esempio che se ne fa [qui](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2011/02/03/ripassiamo-la-particella-ci/): *lavori **con lui**? Sì, **ci** lavoro spesso.*

Comment: @Charo - scusa ma in realtà si usa al posto di "gli".  "È meglio se gli parli", vs "è meglio se ci parli".

Comment: Penso che il problema provenga dal fatto che il verbo "parlare" ammette sia la preposizione "con" che la preposizione "a". "Parla con lui" corrisponde a "parlaci", mentre "parla a lui" corrisponde a "parlagli".

Comment: @Charo - può essere, in realtà le particelle pronominali sono molto usate, anche se spesso a sproposito, per cui sono entrate  con forza nel linguaggio comune. Tieni conto ad esempio che la puoi usare anche al plurale.  "I parlo a loro" vs  "io ci parlo". Nel linguaggio parlato tutto quello che semplifica la stuttura della frase viene molto usato.

Comment: Ha perfettamente ragione @Charo: sarebbe bene chiarire il fatto che “ci lavoro”, “ci vado a spasso” etc., dove “ci” sta per “con lui/lei/loro” è perfettamente corretto (nel senso che è conforme alla norma dell'italiano standard) e non ha nulla di popolare o regionale. “Ci do un regalo” (= “gli do un regalo”), invece è diffuso in alcune regioni e alcuni registri linguistici ma non è ammesso dall'italiano standard. “Ci parlo” è ambiguo perché, come fa notare Charo, “parlare” si può costruire a seconda dei casi sia con “a” che con “con”.

Comment: @DaG - non ne sono convinto, posta tu una risposta con queste considerazione. Poi io cancello la mia. Nessun problema.

Comment: Ma la tua risposta va benissimo, @Gio. Indipendentemente dalle tue opinioni personali, lì c'è scritto tutto nella corretta formulazione del Sabatini-Coletti. Mi limitavo a sottolinearlo.

Comment: Oddio... veramente è proprio difficile capire questo... Molto più difficile di quello che pensava. Ma non impossibile. Grazie a Dio ho domandato questo, perché adesso capiró piú molte cose. Devo prendere alcuni minuti per leggere e releggere questo finchè capirlo hahaha. Davvero, Grazie a tutti, mi hanno aiutato moltissimo tutti. Vi ringrazio tanto.

Comment: “Ci” è una parola apparentemente innocua, ma complessa, @Hamr. Leggi bene le voci che le dedicano i dizionari. Qualcosa puoi trovare anche nella risposta accettata [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/29/when-can-ci-be-used-to-mean-it), che nonostante la lunghezza non è completa.

Comment: A me sembra che il punto chiave qui sia che la sostituzione gli->ci viene usata in italiano; la sostituzione gli->vi invece no. In alcuni utilizzi ci e vi sono intercambiabili, ma in questo no.

Comment: Ho deciso di dare un voto negativo a questa risposta perché non sono d'accordo con l'affermazione iniziale, che sugerisce che l'uso di "ci" nella frase della domanda sia una sostituzione di "gli" con "ci" considerata informale o regionale.

Answer (score 2):

La frase del tuo libro è perfettamente corretta in italiano standard e va intesa in questo modo:

> Sei stato troppo duro con lui! Forse è meglio se parli **con lui** da padre a figlio.

Come spiega l'[articolo dell'enciclopedia Treccani che riguarda la particella "ci"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La-grammatica-italiana)/):

> riferito a una persona, è corretto solo per significare ‘con lui’, ‘con lei’, ‘con loro’, quando questi pronomi (o il nome della persona) siano già stati espressi o si possano facilmente sottintendere
>
> Con lui è tanto tempo che non **ci** vado più
>
> **Ci** usciva già da un anno, quando si sono fidanzati

Anche l'*Italiano* di Serianni, nella sezione VII.48 spiega:

> *Ci* può referirsi anche a esseri animati, purché corrisponda a un pronome dimostrativo o personale costruito con le preposizioni *con*, *su*, *da*, *in*: «Enzo voleva [...] conoscere la gente, *andarci* d'accordo» (Bianciardi, cit. in BRUNET 1985: 94; =andare d'accordo con essa); «è una persona seria: puoi *contarci*» (= contare su di lui / su di lei); «Perché non lasci il bambino ai nonni? – Ma è lui che non *ci* vuole andare» (=andare da loro); «da buon musulmano, credo in Dio. A torto o a ragione *ci* credo» (Fallaci, cit. in BRUNET 1985: 95; =credo in lui).

Tuttavia, il verbo "parlare" ammette anche la preposizione "a" per riferirsi a una persona, quindi si potrebbe dire

> Forse è meglio se parli **a lui** da padre a figlio.

In questo caso, il pronome da usare è "gli" perché si tratta di un complemento di termine:

> Forse è meglio se **gli** parli da padre a figlio.

L'[articolo dell'enciclopedia Treccani che riguarda la particella "ci"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) spiega:

> È invece di uso popolare, quindi da evitarsi, l’uso del *ci* nel senso di ‘a lui’, ‘a lei’, ‘a loro’
>
> L’ho guardato e **ci** ho detto
>
> A Maria **ci** ho telefonato l’altra sera
>
> **Ci** insegneremo a vivere, a tutti questi bambini.

E anche nell'*Italiano* di Serianni (sezione VII.49), si può leggere:

> Non accettabile, invece, l'uso di *ci* come complemento di termine riferito alla 3ª o alla 6ª persona: «ci dico», 'gli, le dico, dico loro'.Si tratta di un'uso presente in tutt'Italia, ma limitato al livello linguistico più popolare (cfr. CORTELAZZO 1972: 90-91).

Comment: In catalano abbiamo lo stesso fenomeno e ho scoperto casualmente che se ne parla [qui](https://www.racocatala.cat/forums/fil/80863/idees-campanyes-normalitzacio-linguistica?pag=1#2150556) ("hi" corrisponde al "ci" italiano, mentre "li" è il pronome catalano equivalente al "gli" italiano).

Comment: "Con lui è tanto tempo che non ci vado più" è un poco ridondante, potrebbe tranquillamente essere sostituito da "Con lui è tanto tempo che non vado più".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:   È una dislocazione a sinistra (vedi, per esempio, [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11145/di-tempo-ormai-ce-n%c3%a8-poco/11152#11152)): la ripresa del complemento dislocato con un clitico si dà in quasi tutte (tutte?) le lingue romanze.

Comment: A me non pare. Anche "A me mi piace" è una dislocazione?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Vedi [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10876/). E cosa non ti pare, scusa?

Comment: Posto che io voglia dislocare a sinistra, sento una differenza tra frasi che non si possono costruire diversamente, es. "Di tempo ce n'è poco" (prova a costruirla senza "ce") e frasi dove invece si può: "Con lui è tanto tempo che non [ci] vado più". Da qui il mio "ridondante". Allora, io non chiamerei dislocazione una ripetizione ridondante. Ritengo che quando una cosa (es. dislocazione) viene usata nel modo errato, perda il suo scopo e quindi non sia più la stessa cosa che voleva essere (cioè una dislocazione).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Perché non poni una domanda al riguardo? Mi sembra un argomento interessante.

Comment: Grazie per il tuo interesse. Non volevo arrivare fino a questo punto, e poi non ho tempo di redigere una domanda fatta bene. Ciao.