# Dubbio sull'uso di certe combinazioni di clitici col verbo "avvicinare"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, particles

(1) Se ho capito bene l'informazione di questa [tabella dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/#gallery-in-text-5), in italiano si possono fare le sostituzioni seguenti:

> - Si avvicina a me --> "mi si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a te --> "ti si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a lui --> "gli si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a lei --> "le si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a noi --> "ci si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a voi --> "vi si avvicina"
> - Si avvicina a loro --> "gli si avvicina" (se ammettiamo l'uso di "gli" come forma atona della terza persona plurale del pronome personale complemento di termine)
> - Si avvicina a un posto --> "ci si avvicina" oppure "vi si avvicina".

(2) Invece, secondo la tabella della Treccani,  non si usano le forme "*mi ti avvicino", "*mi gli avvicino", "*mi le avvicino", "*mi ti avvicini", "*gli ti avvicini", "*le ti avvicini", "*mi gli avvicini", "*mi le avvicini", ecc., per esprimere respettivamente "mi avvicino a te", "mi avvicino a lui", "mi avvicino a lei", "ti avvicini a me", "ti avvicini a lui", "ti avvicini a lei", "mi avvicini a lui", "mi avvicini a lei", ecc., anche se qualche occorrenza se ne trova su Internet e questo può significare che qualcuna si usa molto poco (anche in castigliano e in catalano certe combinazioni di pronomi non sono possibili o non si usano).

(3) Quello che, sempre secondo la tabella della Treccani, sì si usa è:

> - Mi avvicino a un posto --> "mi ci avvicino".
> - Ti avvicini a un posto --> "ti ci avvicini".
> - Ci avviciniamo a un posto --> "vi ci avviciniamo".
> - Vi avvicinate a un posto --> "vi ci avvicinate".
> - Si avvicinano a un posto --> "ci si avvicinano"

Ora, in catalano, adoperamo il clitico "hi" in molte delle situazioni che ho indicato con il numero (2) e "hi" si usa in catalano in un modo abbastanza simile alla particella "ci" italiana. Per esempio:

> - M'acosto a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "m'hi acosto"
> - T'acostes a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "t'hi acostes"
> - M'acostes a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "m'hi acostes"
> - M'acostes a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "m'hi acostes"
> - T'acosto a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "t'hi acosto"
> - M'acosta a ell/ella/ells/elles --> "m'hi acosta"
> - ...

Infatti, in catalano usiamo queste combinazioni di due clitici anche con verbi che non hanno niente a che vedere con il moto, come "assemblar-se" ("assomigliarsi") o "presentar-se" ("presentarsi"), ma forse è meglio chiedere sull'uso dei clitici con i correspondenti verbi italiani in un'altra domanda.

Allora, la mia domanda è: succede lo stesso in italiano? Cioè, per esempio, posso esprimere "mi avvicino a lui/lei/loro" come "mi ci avvicino", "ti avvicini a lui/lei/loro" come "ti ci avvicini" o "mi avvicini a lui/lei/loro" come "mi ci avvicini"? E posso dire, per esempio, "ti ci avvicino" intendendo "ti avvicino a lui/lei/loro"?

La domanda riguarda non solo lo scritto formale, ma anche il parlato di registro medio.

Difatti, la tabella della Treccani sopra menzionata ha le combinazioni "mi ci", "ti ci" e "vi ci" con il "ci" locativo, ma non se si possa considerare che il complemento 
"a lui/lei/loro" del verbo "avvicinare" abbia un ruolo locativo. Io sono miope e, se vado senza gli occhiali, mi può accedere di accorgermi di starmi avvicinando a qualcosa, ma non sapere se si tratta di un albero, un cane oppure una persona. Scherzi a parte, è tanto diverso "mi avvicino a quel fiore" di "mi avvicino al cane" o "mi avvicino all'insegnante"?

L'unica informazione al riguardo che sono riuscita a trovare è nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti, nel quale appare un esempio di "mi ci avvicino" con "ci" riferito a "al cane" e si spiega che "ci" ha a volte il valore di "a lui/lei/loro":

> Minor padronanza della lingua denota l'uso di *ci* per *gli/le/loro*, come in «ci dico», pur non poco usato nel parlato. *Ci* è, oltre ad avverbio di luogo, pronome personale atono e non solo di 1ª persona plurale («ci ha visti», «ci ha rivolto un saluto»), ma anche di 3ª singolare o plurale col valore di «con/a lui/lei/loro», come nelle frasi tipiche del parlato: «con Pietro ci parlerò domani», «con Pietro e Angelo non voglio averci a che fare», «al cane non ci bada nessuno», «al cane non mi ci avvicino».

Tuttavia, questa spiegazione non mi è del tutto chiara: questo uso di "ci" appare soltanto nel parlato? Oppure, con "frasi tipiche del parlato", Coletti unicamente ci sta suggerendo che gli esempi che ha fatto hanno una dislocazione a sinistra e, per questa ragione, sono costrutti caratteristici della comunicazione orale (e fa esempi con dislocazioni a sinistra semplicemente per far sì che si capisca bene quali sono i nomi a cui sostituiscono i pronomi)?

Per rendere le cose più confuse, le spiegazioni sull'uso di "ci" riferito a esseri animati (3ª persona singolare e plurale) dell'Enciclopedia Treccani e dell'*Italiano* di Serianni che appaiono in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8396/) sembrano essere in contraddizione con l'affermazione di Coletti sul fatto che "ci" può anche avere il valore di "a lui/lei/loro".

Comment: La discussione è stata molto interessante, ma i commenti non sono un luogo adatto per le lunghe discussioni. Per favore continuatela in [questa chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104496/discussion-on-question-by-charo-dubbio-sulluso-di-certe-combinazioni-di-clitici)

Answer (score 1):

La domanda è molto lunga, mi limito a esprimermi su un paio di questioni.

> posso esprimere "mi avvicino a lui/lei/loro" come "mi ci avvicino", "ti avvicini a lui/lei/loro" come "ti ci avvicini" o "mi avvicini a lui/lei/loro" come "mi ci avvicini"? E posso dire, per esempio, "ti ci avvicino" intendendo "ti avvicino a lui/lei/loro"?

Per me la risposta è sì: capirei ognuno degli esempi qui sopra attribuendogli il significato che hai suggerito. Una specie di regola (credo automatica, non ragionata) è che, in tali frasi, il primo clitico è il soggetto / complemento oggetto, cioè chi o che cosa si muove; il restante clitico indica verso chi o che cosa ci si avvicina. Ma nota che in "ci si avvicina" i ruoli sono invertiti, forse perché la forma è pienamente riflessiva e la particella *si* viene spostata da dopo il verbo a prima di esso.

> affermazione di Coletti sul fatto che "ci" può anche avere il valore di "a lui/lei/loro"

E' vero quello che dice Coletti, ma non si tratta di ottimo Italiano: *a lui* dovrebbe essere *gli*; *a lei le*; *a loro loro*. Il verbo *parlare* può essere usato con due casi diversi: "Parlo a Coletti" -> "Gli parlo"; "Parlo con Coletti" -> "Ci parlo"; entrambi i casi sono corretti, e sono quasi equivalenti tranne che la particella *con* suggerisce una maggiore interazione fra i due soggetti. Però la somiglianza dei due casi non è una buona ragione per confonderli, per me.