# Dubbio su alcuni usi della particella "ci"

Tags: grammar, particles

Ho letto un po' sulla particella *ci* che sustituisce "a/in/con + qualcosa/qualcuno".

Ad esempio:

> Sei uscita con Roberta?
>
> Sì, ci sono uscita per un caffè

(Quest'esempio si trova su https://learnamo.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-ci-in-italian/).

Seguendo la stessa cosa, ho scritto:

> Ci piace visitare le nostre famiglie e ci trascorriamo molto tempo (ci = con loro)
>
> Anne è qui, ci vado al mare (con lei).

Ma qualcuno mi ha detto che queste frasi non erano corrette e che avrei dovuto scrivere:

> ci trascorriamo molto tempo insieme.
>
> ci vado insieme al mare.

Ma mi ha detto anche che  è preferibile non usare questa particella in tali usi  (perché è un po' innaturale e forzato). 
Non so di che devo fare caso, ho un sacco di opinioni diverse. Vorrei sapere come usare la  particella *ci* in questi contesti senza sembrare innaturale.

Comment: Le frasi sono corrette per il linguaggio parlato informale. Evita “ci dico”, cioè “ci=a lui/lei” sebbene sia adoperato piuttosto (o troppo) spesso.

Comment: Se è solo questione di opinioni, allora devo dire che le prime due frasi sono davvero brutte. Perché è naturale/corretto dire "Prendo il caffé con lei", ma "Ci prendo il caffé" no: sembra dialettale, in realtà è brutta perché incompleta.

Comment: Domanda correlata:  https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8381/.

Comment: @egreg:   Tuttavia, dalla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La-grammatica-italiana)/): "riferito a una persona, è corretto solo per significare ‘con lui’, ‘con lei’, ‘con loro’, quando questi pronomi (o il nome della persona) siano già stati espressi o si possano facilmente sottintendere".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica La frase in esame non è “ci prendo il caffè”.

Comment: @Charo Non capisco il “tuttavia”, dal momento che nelle frasi citate il significato è proprio quello.

Comment: @egreg: Lo stesso articolo della Treccani riporta: "È invece di uso popolare, quindi da evitarsi, l’uso del *ci* nel senso di ‘a lui’, ‘a lei’, ‘a loro’". Quindi, fa una differenza tra questi usi della particella "ci".

Comment: @Charo Continuo a non capire: nel mio commento dico appunto di evitare l’uso nel senso di “a lui/lei/loro”

Comment: @egreg: Allora sono io che non ho capito il senso di "Le frasi sono corrette per il linguaggio parlato informale", scusa. Comunque, da quanto ho letto sulla Treccani o sul Serianni (si veda risposta all'altra domanda), non mi sembra si tratti di un uso infomale di "ci".

Comment: @egreg: "Prendo il caffè con lei" / "Vado al mare con lei"; "Ci prendo il caffé" / "Ci vado al mare" hanno struttura paragonabile, solo che l'esempio del caffé mostra meglio il problema ed è per questo che l'ho citato. La particella *ci* ha diverse valenze, e per questo può generare frasi ambigue che io trovo brutte.

Comment: Da quanto ho capito io (si veda [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8396/) per più dettagli), le frasi della domanda sono grammaticalmente corrette (non solo nel parlato informale). Tuttavia, l'articolo della Treccani a cui ho fatto riferimento insiste sul fatto di usare la particella *ci* soltanto "quando questi pronomi (o il nome della persona) siano già stati espressi o si possano facilmente sottintendere". Succede che, con le frasi fuori contesto, mi sia difficile di valutare se tali frasi si possano o no capire (ho l'impressione che questo sia il problema).

Comment: Grazie a tutti  per le spiegazioni.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> la particella *ci* sostituisce "a/in/con + qualcosa/qualcuno".

Credo che, per questo motivo, una frase che usa la particella *ci* ma non permette di capire *quale* delle sostituzioni sia quella voluta, possa risultare ambigua, incompleta, quindi un po' strana, a volte perfino brutta. Non si tratta di un problema grammaticale, solo di stile e chiarezza. Per esempio in:

> Sei uscita con Roberta?  -- Sì, ci sono uscita per un caffè

la particella *ci* può essere collegata/richiamata a "con Roberta", quindi la risposta, svolta completamente, risulta *"Sì, (con Roberta) sono uscita per un caffé"*.

Invece nella frase:

> Ci piace visitare le nostre famiglie e ci trascorriamo molto tempo

manca, prima di *ci*, una particella *a/in/con* che permetta di capire chiaramente se il suo significato è *a*, *in*, o *con*. Si capice ugualmente, perché *"molto tempo a loro"* e *"molto tempo in loro"* non hanno un valore semantico corretto. Aggiungere la parola "insieme" aiuta perché si riesce a immaginare la costruzione "insieme con loro".

L'ultima frase:

> Anne è qui, ci vado al mare [(con lei)].

presenta lo stesso problema di incompletezza, si sente che manca qualche cosa (un po' meno). Un po' diverso sarebbe:

> Anne è qui, ci parlo

che potrebbe significare "parlo a lei" oppure "parlo con lei", entrambe corrette (certo non "parlo in lei"). Dato che entrambe le costruzioni con *a* e *con* sono plausibili, forse la frase è meno ambigua.

Una frase che, a me personalmente, suona meno male è:

> Mi piace la mia casa, ci trascorro molto tempo [dentro]

che presuppone che la particella *ci* sostituisca "in essa" ma, grammaticalmente, potrebbe pure sostituire "con essa" (non *"a essa"* perché non avrebbe proprio senso). Non riesco a spiegare il perché questa frase suoni meglio, forse è solo una sensazione.